# How to type check component children with Preact and TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, preact

Is it possible to type check a components children with TypeScript (v3.0.1) and Preact (v8.3.1)? In React there is a `ReactElement<T>` for that. Is there something similar in Preact?

I have a `menu` component, which can only have `menuItem` child components. How can I enforce that in Preact with TypeScript? With React I could do something like:

```
interface Props {
    children?: React.ReactElement<MenuItem>[] | React.ReactElement<MenuItem>;
}
```

I know that that `ReactElement` is implemented in `preact-compat`, but I don't want to use it.

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Now the simplest option is probably the `ComponentChildren` type (see this commit: https://github.com/preactjs/preact/commit/cd422d047f6d21607ff980c84b9c4ac1845ca798). For example:

```
import { h } from "preact";

import type { ComponentChildren } from "preact";

type Props = {
  children: ComponentChildren;
}

export function ComponentWithChildren(props: Props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Preact's equivalent of `ReactElement` is called `VNode` (Virtual DOM Node). I'm by no means a TypeScript expert, but I believe your example could work as follows:

```
interface Props {
    children?: VNode<MenuItem>[] | VNode<MenuItem>;
}
```

Prior to Preact 8.3.0 I think we relied on `JSX.Element` instead of `VNode`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Well it compiles, but it also compiles, when the children are something else than a `MenuItem` like a `<div>`.

Comment: Are you using Preact 8.3.0+?

Comment: Yes, I'm on `"preact": "^8.3.1",`.